# Was Michael the protagonist of the movie within the movie of Thriller?

Tags: plot-explanation, michael-jackson-thriller

In Michael Jackson's Thriller, the video starts with Michael and his date on a walk. He's affected by the full moon and turns into a hideous man wolf, attacking his date. Cut to Michael and his date sitting in a theater watching the previous scene. Ergo, we are told that the werewolf scene is a movie and never happened. The movie theater marquee says ***"Vincent Price"*** and ***"Thriller"***. As such, we are watching a film where the main characters are watching a film.

My question is, was the first scene a projection? Are we to believe that Michael and his date are projecting themselves onto the actors of the film, imagining themselves as part of the action? Or were Michael and his date the actual actors in the film? Surely actors will watch their own films, even in their private lives outside of major film first screenings. Many actors have no idea how their scenes came out or the full plot until after the film comes out.

If not Michael, was Vincent the main protagonist in the film, or the director? Vincent himself was a major movie star, and often acted in supernatural horror films.

Comment: Their dialogue sure doesn't sound like they're the actors, they just sound like a couple of teens who watched a horror movie. But remember that *the whole thing is actually the girl's dream*. It doesn't have to make much sense.

Comment: @walt at what point did her dream start? Overactive imagination on the way home? Or did you mean a word of God that the whole thing was a dream, so three levels of inception? If the former, it still leaves the main question unanswered.  Also, if it was a dream up to when Michael tells her it's safe, the ending with Michael eyes call it in question.

Comment: Hmm, I just assumed it. I guess it *is* possible they went to his house *after* the movie and she fell asleep. But as the ending suggests, it's all supposed to be convoluted horror trope homage, so I never really thought about the plot structure that seriously.

Answer (score 1):

I have always assumed they were projecting themselves into the action onscreen. Vincent Price would not have been a teenager in a car, so he may have been the star, but not that character. He would have "played" a werewolf hunter or such.
This is a common and enduring trope, characters imagining themselves in a movie. 
The zombie dance could have been "real". Perhaps the girl fainted in the graveyard and when she came to, Michael (who was actually evil) convinced her it was a dream.

Answer (score 1):

The video starts with Jackson turning into a Were*Cat* (as opposed to a more familiar Were*Wolf*).  Jackson's girlfriend becomes scared and gets up and leaves the theater.  Jackson hands off his popcorn to another moviegoer.  At this point, a few things are debatable:

1. It's *likely* that if Jackson's girlfriend was actually the actress, she wouldn't be as scared because she'd have understood the filmmaking process
2. It's *likely* that Jackson wasn't in the movie because no one even gave him a second look when he got up to follow her out, not even the guy he handed the popcorn to.

On their walk home, Jackson turns into a *zombie*, not a *werecat*.  This is a new event, most likely dreamed up by the sleeping girlfriend who may have perceived him to be that way in her dream.

At the end, after they leave the house, Jackson is again a *werecat* (as seen by his eyes).  This was most likely done to create some type of ambiguity as to what was real and what was fiction in the preceding events.

So, with that all in mind, I'd say the opening was most likely a projection of Jackson and his girlfriend imagining themselves in the movie.

Answer (score 0):

Since the bulk of the movie was a dream, I'm uncertain. If anyone was the protagonist, I'd say that the girl was. Also, we know where her dream ended, yet Michael's eyes glow at the end. I find that sinister and question if it all really was a dream, or at what point she started dreaming. I don't think we'll ever really know.